# How to set perodic reminder using alarm manager?

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager, android-alarms

In my application i have many goal each goal have specific date wise or week day ( like Monday , Tuesday , Sunday reminder ) and specific time set option reminder. I have stored that value inside into sqlite database . Anyone can suggest me any tutorial there i can find any idea about that . I want to show notification reminder based on reminder date time weekly value one by one . Like goal one is set reminder time 10:30 Am and days are selected Monday and Wednesday . and Goal 2 is set reminder time 4:00 and date is 2, 22,24.

I have tried using Alarm manager but i can get any proper result . anyone can give me simple solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the desk clock github:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/

Start with AlarmStateManager#updateNextAlarm(Context context) 
And the rest is fine the alarms package.

Take into account the implementation there is very battle tested.
Setting a truly reliable reminder system is pretty tricky to get right on, so make so you understand the project.

Comment: It's the relevant file inside the DeskClockFragment project. clone and explore the mentioned method